# Cannot edit a C array by index

Tags: c, arrays, assign

I am a noob to **C** programming (I come from the lands of **JS** and **PHP**), and as a learning exercise I attempted to write a program that asks for the user's name, and then prints it back out with the small exception of changing the first letter to a `z`. However, when I went to compile the code it returned the following `error` message in reference to the line `name[0] = "Z";`

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Is there a reason I can't assign a value to a specific index in a `char` `array`?

(Note: I have tried typecasting `"Z"` to a char but it just threw the `error`

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size`)

Comment: Single quotes not double quotes

Answer (score 5):

Unlike some languages that do not distinguish between strings and characters, C requires a different syntax for characters (vs. a single-character string).

You need to use single quotes:

```
name[0] = 'Z';
```

The error is quite cryptic, though. It is trying to say that `"Z"`, a single-character C string, gets assigned to `name[0]`, an integral type of `char`. C strings are arrays; arrays are convertible to pointers. Hence, C treats this as a pointer-to-int assignment without a cast.

Comment: Thank you very much. JS and PHP do not have anything like this so I had no idea.

Answer (score 4):

replace `name[0] = "Z";` with `name[0] = 'Z';`.

'single-quatation' is for an character `element` and "double-quatation" is for a string assignment.

Answer (score 2):

In C, single quotes and double quotes carry different meanings. In fact, there is no concept of "Strings" in C. You have the basic char data type, where a char is represented by single quotes. To represent strings, you store them as an array of chars. For example,

```
char text[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
```

This is just a more tedious way of writing

```
char text[] = "hello";
```

This is exactly the same as the first example, with the exception that there is a null character `\0` at the end (this is how C detects the end of "strings"). It's the same as saying `char text[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};` except now you can work with your array more easily, if you want to do string based processing on it.

---

Coming to your question, if you want to index a certain character in a "string", you'd need to access it by it's index in the array.

So, `text[0]` returns the character `h` which is of type `char`. To assign a different value, you must assign a single quoted char as so:

```
text[0] = 'Z';
```